# Using FullCalendar want to change property of event B when event A is changed

Tags: fullcalendar

Using FullCalendar is there a way to change the event property of another event on the same day as the event that was clicked? I have 2 events on each day and when event A changes I want to change the property of event B. Any ideas?

Comment: You should show your code, what you have tried

Comment: eventClick: function (boEventClicked, jsEvent, view) {
                debugger;
                if (boEventClicked.type === 'UOC')
                    if (!boEventClicked.readonly)
                        SetUOC(boEventClicked);
                    else
                        return;
                else
                    SetAttendance(boEventClicked);
                    //HERE WHEN ATTANDANCE EVENT IS CLICKED, IF IT IS 'PRESENT', UOC EVENTS READONLY PROPERTY SHOULD BE SET TO FALSE FOR THAT DAY.
            },

Comment: add it to you post please and use the code tag so it is easier to read

Comment: add code to the question please, that's unreadable. Comments are for comments and discussion, the question text is for code snippets. Thankyou.

Comment: But in theory yes what you're asking for is possible - you can easily fetch all the other events which occur on a particular day by using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents and doing a date filter in the callback (based on the day(s) the clicked event occurs on). Then you can modify the property of the other events it returns, and run https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rerenderEvents to apply the changes. As Juan said, did you try anything, or even read the documentation to try and work out how it could be done? All the functionality you need is already available to you.

Comment: Yes, I later tried clientEvents, looped through them, matched the date with the date of the event that was clicked, then matched the title and was able to set the property of the other event for that date! sealed it with updateEvent! Thank You All.

Comment: Also sorry about the code in my previous post.....this was the first time i used this forum.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question and accept it, perhaps you could post your solution code for others' benefit in the future...

Answer (score 0):

here's how it worked:

if (boEventClicked.type === "Present") {

```
 //restore UOC event to editable when attendance event is set to 'Present'
 var aDate = moment(boEventClicked.start, "MM/DD/YYYY");

 $.each($('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'), 
      function (idx, eventitem) {
            var uDate = moment(eventitem.start, "MM/DD/YYYY");

            if ((moment(uDate).isSame(aDate)) && eventitem.type === 'UOC') {
                eventitem.readonly = false;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventitem);
            }
        });

        return;
    }
```